# Update driver for scangearmp2-3.50-1-deb

Tags: drivers, 20.04, ubuntu-mate

The scangearmp2 application in scangearmp2-3.50-1-deb does not work with Ubuntu Mate 20.04.

My printer is a Canon TS9120.

The Canon site has no newer driver listed.

I need help in finding a newer driver if it exists.

Comment: Does the "Document Scanner" app in Ubuntu MATE 20.04 work for you? It works with our Canon MAXIFY MB2300 out of the box so I never bothered to install scangearmp2

Comment: No, Document scanner, along with other scanners do not work. @Organic Marble

Comment: I wonder if it is not the driver then, but some other problem. What model of scanner / printer do you have?

Comment: Not sure about that. Long ago in the 14.04 days I struggled to get this scanner to work.  Tried so many things, I am not sure which one did the trick.